# Making remote web requests in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, testing, rspec, functional-testing

I have a php app that is going through a migration to rails. We are currently sharing the session from php to rails using memcached. The problem that has arisen is now testing has become difficult. I can't make remote requests using capybara to write functional that really test the full application.

The only solution I have come up with is mocking out the memcached communication, which isn't what I really want in integration testing.

Does anyone have any better options for this? I've tried other capybara drivers, such as mechanize, but I can't get external pages to load.

Comment: what is the error, exception or whatever you are experiencing? why shouldn't this work with normal integration testing?

Comment: I'm getting no route defined errors, which make sense, since the routes are actually part of another application.

Comment: so what does this have to do with drivers?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired Culerity driver?: [Capybara::Session documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session)

```
# NB! untested!
require 'capybara/session'

session = Capybara::Session.new(:culerity)
session.visit('http://www.google.com')

session.fill_in('q', :with => 'Capybara')
session.click_button('Search')
session.should have_content('Capybara')
```